# The term alias is not recognized

Tags: firebase, flutter, alias, keytool

While trying to get the debug certificate fingerprint to be used in firebase we got an error claiming that keytool is not recognized, but we downloaded jdk and set the path then this error appeared:

```
-alias : The term '-alias' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystor ...
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-alias:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you're not typing the full command. You should be running:

`keytool -list -v -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass <store_password> -keypass <key_password>` (Where `store_password` and `key_password` default to `android`.

The output of this command will include the SHA1 and SHA256 fingerprints of your certificate which you enter in the Firebase console.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You should use this command, it will work!

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "%USERPROFILE%/.android/debug.keystore"
```

Password will be: `android`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

keytool -list -v -keystore %USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android