# Firebase self sign-in issue

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, certificate

I am building an android based mobile application using flutter. When I want to add firebase to my app, I am facing an issue on `Debug signing certificate SHA-1`. I need to enter this command `keytool -list -v \-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore`. When I enter this command in my vscode terminal as I am building using the IDE, I get this error message.

```
Error message: -alias : The term '-alias' is not recognized as the 
name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check 
the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct, and try again.
At line:2 char:1
+ -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystor ...
+ ~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-alias:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS D:\puvan\Desktop\Food Donation App(Food2Gather)\food2gather> --help
At line:1 char:3
+ --help
+   ~
Missing expression after unary operator '--'.
At line:1 char:3
+ --help
+   ~~~~
Unexpected token 'help' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], 
ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
```

I am not sure why this error message occurs and I am quite new to flutter and firebase. Still in the learning process. Can you help to tell which part I am doing wrong and how to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The term alias is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244837/the-term-alias-is-not-recognized)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Flutter programmer, but I believe that this was already asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244837/the-term-alias-is-not-recognized).

If it is, please remember to search in stack overflow the non-case-specific part of the error, to improve your chances of finding help, without needing to ask a question and wait for an answer . Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the ability to mark as a duplicate, but this appears to be a duplicate of this question: [The term alias is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244837/the-term-alias-is-not-recognized)

According to the existing Solution-marked answer, you need to run the following command in full: `keytool -list -v -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass <store_password> -keypass <key_password>` (Where `store_password` and `key_password` default to android).